# how to convert python list[a,b,c,d] to [a:b, c:d] format

Tags: python, django, opencv, image-processing

How do I convert a python list to the `[a:b, c:d]` format?

This format is used in cropping of images in python-opencv.

Suppose that I have cropping dimensions of an image in a list `cropDim` but don't know how to make it into opencv acceptable format as `image[a:b, c:d]`.

```
import cv2
def crop(cropDim):
    bimage = cv2.imread("nor.jpg")
    cropped = bimage[a:b, c:d]
    cv2.imwrite('nor-crop.jpg', cropped)
```

Comment: `a,b,c,d = cropDim` ? maybe ... we have no idea what cropdim looks like ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's get the terminology straight - that's not a Python list, it's an array with two dimensions. You're trying to do a slice on it.

```
cropped = bimage[cropDim[0]:cropDim[1], cropDim[2]:cropDim[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

k so lets play the guessing game with good assumption :)
as per the heading it says how to convert python list[a,b,c,d] to [a:b, c:d] format:

so we will assume cropDim = [a,b,c,d] and output required is [a:b,c:d]

```
cropDim = [a,b,c,d]
templist1 = []
templist2 = []
for i,item in enumerate(cropDim):
    if i % 2 ==0:
        templist1.append(item)
    else:
        templist2.append(item)
result = map(':'.join,zip(templist1,templist2))
print result #behold the power of assumption
```